# Nodejs Cannot find package

Tags: node.js

After command node aoo.js I see this:
node:internal/process/esm_loader:74
internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'C:\Users\yanat\formreport\node_modules\express' imported from C:\Users\yanat\formreport\app.js
I've already tried install express, webpack, browserify and updated node.js

```
#app.js

import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
import cookieParser from 'cookieParser';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import expressHandlebars from 'express-handlebars'
import flash from 'connect-flash';
import session from 'express-session';
import  mongoose from 'mongoose';
import passport from 'passport';

require('./config/passport');

const app = express();


#package.json

    {
  "name": "formreport",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "yana taranets",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.2",
    "joi": "^13.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.13",
    "morgan": "^1.8.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "Express": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: what is your node version please? `node --version`

Comment: just some common checks also:
- `npm install` in you root folder
- change `"main": "app.js"` to `"main": "aoo.js"`

Comment: there is also a strange devDependency that I don't know about "Express" uninstall it you don't know either